# What do the extra numbers next to a SO user's name mean?

Tags: support

The number next to your name in an SO post makes sense. That's your ranking on the site. By there are 3 numbers after that, next to small colored circles.

Below is my name with the various numbers next to it.

[image: SO Image with mystery numbers]

What do the 9, the 64, and the 130 indicate?

I've been an active SO member for quite a few years now, but I have no idea what those other numbers stand for.

Comment: Wowzers. 7 down-votes in 4 minutes? Are questions about the meaning and function of the site verboten on Meta SO? I thought that's what the meta site was for.

Comment: How can you reach 60k reputation and not know what those numbers are :|

Comment: @DuncanC Just like the main site, you are expected to do a modicum of research. The downvotes probably come from that (I know mine does)

Comment: Also the fact that gold silver and bronze colours as medals, badges etc are universal to everything you could work it out handy.

Comment: I suspect someone is after some kind of "Trolling Meta" hat :)

Comment: -15 now? Jeez, tough audience. I really did try to figure it out before posting. Now that somebody told me what they're for, it seems obvious, but it is NOT apparent what they stand for.

Comment: It can be perceived as humble bragging as well and some people would down vote for that

Comment: Also it's meta so it doesn't matter anyway :)

Comment: @Dave, call me an idiot, but I really, truly had no idea what the numbers meant.

Comment: Shouldn't this be merged to stackexchange meta instead?

Comment: I think the answer is that Safari, my preferred browser, does to show the hints for these numbers when you hover over them. I tried it, and the hints **do** show up in Chrome.

Comment: I can't reproduce that, Duncan. The tooltips on the badges show up just fine for me on Safari.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They are the badge counts for the user.  The color represents the badge type.  So in your picture you have 9 gold badges, 64 silver badges and 130 bronze badges.

Comment: what is the "badges" means so? LOL 

Answer (score 16):

Hover your mouse over them and all will be revealed.

Those are the numbers of badges you have in each class (gold, silver and bronze).

Comment: Cool, thanks. Hovering doesn't work for me however. (Mac OS/Safari)

Comment: @DuncanC Try hovering over the number.

Comment: Nope. Hovering over an avatar causes a description of the user to pop up, but hovering over a number does... nothing.

Comment: If you go to your profile page, there is a "badges" section with the same number...

Comment: I Just switched to Chrome, and hovering **does** show the meanings of the badge numbers from Chrome. I wonder why it doesn't work on Safari?

Comment: maybe safari doesn't like title attributes on spans.

Answer (score 1):

Picking up from stack overflow documentation: Below is what each color on your profile means

Bronze Badge
Bronze badges encourage users to try out new features on the site. They are easy to get if you try!

Silver Badge
Silver badges are less common than bronze ones. You'll need to plan your strategy to get one of these.

Gold Badge
Gold badges recognize important contributions from members of the community. They are rarely awarded.